# ASP Net Identity - Adding a second authentication cookie

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, cookies

I'm trying to use a second cookie so that other applications in a subdomain can validate, if a user is logged in in my application. However i don't trust the other applications thats why I'm planning to use two Authentication Cookies. One for my own Application (IdentityCookie) and one so that the other Apps can access the login status (SubCookie).

I'm using ASP.NET Identity for cookie creation and account management.

```
        services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>().AddSignInManager<AuthSignInManager<ApplicationUser>>();

        services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
        {
            options.Cookie.SameSite = Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.SameSiteMode.Strict;
            options.CookieManager = new CookieManager();
        });
```

The custom CookieManager is responsible for creating and deleting both Cookies at the same time.

My issue now is that I can't find a way to validate the cookies. I attempted to use a custom Authenticationhandler for the validation of the subCookie, but if I add the following code the IdentityCookie validation stops working:

```
services.AddAuthentication("CookieBearer").AddScheme<BasicAuthenticationOptions, BasicAuthenticationHandler>("CookieBearer", o => {});
```

It seemes like after adding this line only the Custom Handler is used and the one provided by Identity is ignored. Is there any way to add multiple AuthenticationHandlers with ASP.NET Identity? I want to use the custom AuthenticationHandler just as a fallback option. So that if authentication by Identity fails the custom AuthenticationHandler is used.

I know I can chain Authentication Schemes/Methods like this, but I'm not sure how to do it in combination with Identity.

```
services
.AddAuthentication()
.AddJwtBearer("Custom1", options =>
{
    //Configure here
})
.AddJwtBearer("Custom2", options =>
{
    // Configure here
});
```